# Why does this piece of code ensure trueKappa to be positive definite?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, adjacency-matrix, network-analysis

```
Constant <- 1.5

diag(trueKappa) <- constant * rowSums(abs(trueKappa))

diag(trueKappa) <- ifelse(diag(trueKappa)==0,1,diag(trueKappa))

trueKappa <- trueKappa/diag(trueKappa)[row(trueKappa)]

trueKappa <- (trueKappa + t(trueKappa)) / 2
```

The code is written in R, and trueKappa was simulated with the following code

```
library(igraph)    

trueKappa <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(watts.strogatz.game(1,Nvar,nei,p)))
  
# Make edges negative and add weights:
trueKappa[upper.tri(trueKappa)] <- trueKappa[upper.tri(trueKappa)] * sample(c(-1,1),sum(upper.tri(trueKappa)),TRUE,prob=c(propPositive,1-propPositive)) * runif(sum(upper.tri(trueKappa)), min(parRange ),max(parRange ))
      
# Symmetrize:
trueKappa[lower.tri(trueKappa)] <- t(trueKappa [lower.tri(trueKappa)]
```

Thanks in advance for all answers

Comment: One can prove that a diagonally dominant symmetric matrix with positive diagonal entries is positive definite.  This code is (somewhat inefficiently) ensuring that those properties hold for `trueKappa`.

Comment: Hi @Mikael Jagan thank you so much for your answer. I think your answer makes a lot of sense and could be the plausible answer. Do you mind posting a reference for your answer so that I can understand your point further?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435631) proof, which follows from the definitions of [diagonal dominance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) and [positive definiteness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix).